# Do GNS-projections of different tensor factors commute?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be unital $C^*$-algebras and let $\omega$ be a state on a $C^*$-tensor product $A\otimes_\beta B$. Let $(\pi,H,\Omega)$ be the GNS-representation of $\omega$. Let $P_A$ be the projection onto $[\pi(A\otimes1)\Omega]$ and let $P_B$ be the projection onto $[\pi(1\otimes B)\Omega]$. Here $[V]$ denotes the closed linear hull of a subset $V \subset H$.

Is it true that $P_A$ and $P_B$ commute?

I'm interested in these projections because they induce the GNS-representations of the "reduced states" $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$, e.g. $\omega_A(a) =\omega(a\otimes1)$.
Because of uniqueness one has that $(P_A(\pi( \,- \otimes 1)),P_A H,\Omega)$ equivalent to the GNS representation $\omega_A$.

An answer for von Neumann algebras would also be much appreciated, if that's easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is again no.  Take $A=B=\mathbb C^2$, so that $C=A\otimes B = \mathbb C^4$.

The goal is to reduce this to my answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466326/do-gns-projections-corresponding-to-commuting-subalgebras-commute) by choosing an appropriate state.

Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be the canonical basis vectors in $\mathbb C^2$, and choose the state $\phi$ on $C$ such that $\phi(e_i\otimes e_j)=1/3$, for all $i,j$, except for $\phi(e_2\otimes e_1)=0$.

If $(\pi,H,\Omega)$ is the corresponding GNS representation we then have that
$\pi(e_2\otimes e_1)\Omega =0$, and hence
$$
  f_1:= \pi (e_1\otimes e_1)\Omega ,
  $$
$$
  \qquad\ f_2:= \pi (e_1\otimes e_2)\Omega ,\quad \text{and}
  $$
$$
  f_3:= \pi (e_2\otimes e_2)\Omega 
  $$
span $H$.

It is not hard to see that these form a linearly independent set, and hence that $H$ is 3-dimensional.

Given any $a$ in $A$, say $a=(\lambda ,\mu )$, we have that
$$
  \pi (a\otimes 1) =   \pi ((\lambda e_1 + \mu e_2)\otimes 1)= \lambda \pi (e_1\otimes 1) + \mu \pi (e_2\otimes 1),
  $$
so it is easy to see that
$$
  \pi (a\otimes 1)f_1 =   \lambda f_1, \quad \pi (a\otimes 1)f_2 =   \lambda f_2, \quad \text {and} \quad   \pi (a\otimes 1)f_3 =   \mu f_3,
  $$
whence the matrix of $\pi (a\otimes 1)$ in the basis $\{f_1, f_2, f_3\}$ is
$$
  \pmatrix{\lambda  & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & \lambda  & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & \mu }.
  $$
If instead  $b = (\lambda ,\mu )\in  B$, then
$$
  \pi (1\otimes b) =   \pi (1\otimes (\lambda e_1 + \mu e_2)) =\lambda \pi (1\otimes e_1) + \mu \pi (1\otimes e_2),
  $$
so
a similar analysis gives the matrix of $\pi (1\otimes b)$, as being
$$
  \pmatrix{\lambda  & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & \mu  & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & \mu }.
  $$

Identifying $H$ with ${\mathbb C}^3$ via the basis mentioned above we see that $\Omega$ is proportional to $(1,1,1)$, and
$$
  [\pi (A\otimes 1)\Omega ]  =  \{(\lambda , \lambda , \mu ): \lambda , \mu \in {\mathbb C}\},
  $$
and
$$
  [\pi (1\otimes B)\Omega ]  =  \{(\lambda , \mu , \mu ): \lambda , \mu \in {\mathbb C}\},
  $$
whence
$$
  P_A =\pmatrix {1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \cr 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1},
  $$
and
$$
  P_B =\pmatrix { 1&  0 & 0  \cr 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \cr 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 },
  $$
which do not commute.

I am still thinking about what happens when $\phi$ is a product state and I believe the answer is affirmative in that case.

Comment: Looks correct. Thanks! I think for a product state $\omega=\omega_A\otimes\omega_B$ the claim is true: Here the GNS rep. is the tensor product $\pi =\pi_A\otimes \pi_B$, $H=H_A\otimes H_B$ and $\Omega=\Omega_A\otimes\Omega_B$. 
One gets $[\pi(A\otimes1)\Omega] = H_A \otimes \Omega$, so $P_A = 1_{H_A} \otimes (\Omega_B\otimes \overline{\Omega_B})$ which commutes with $P_B = (\Omega_A \otimes \overline{\Omega_A})\otimes 1_{H_B}$, where $(\psi \otimes \overline\phi)\xi =(\xi,\phi)\, \psi$.

Comment: Do you @Ruy have any idea about the case of a pure state in general? Here $\pi$ is irreducible, so $M=\pi(A\otimes 1)''$ and $N=\pi(1\otimes B)''$ are two factors which commute with each other and together generate $\mathcal{B}(H)$ but I can't see why this should imply that $M'=N$. But in the case that $M=N'$, we get $P_AP_B=P_BP_A$ because we always have $P_A\in M'$ and $P_B\in N'$ which should imply the claim because $M$ and $N$ commute. [I reposted this comment because I was told that people will not be notified without the "@"]

Comment: @paci295.  I think I can prove your conjecture for pure states but only when $A$ and $B$ coincide with the algebra of compact operators.

Comment: nice. I also have a proof for that case using the 'Schmidt decomposition'. Did you also use something along those lines? I think one should be able to do something similar if at least one of the reduced states is a type I state (i.e., $\pi_{\omega_A}(A)'' \equiv P_A M = MP_A$ is a type I vN algebra).