# Semi-direct product of Hilbert spaces and commuting projections

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be complex vector spaces equipped with non-negative sesqui-linear forms
$\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle _1$, and $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle _2$, respectively, so that each can be viewed as a
pre-Hilbert space (with possibly degenerate norms).

To a large extent you are welcome to assume that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are indeed Hilbert spaces.

Also let
$$
  \varphi :H_1\times H_2\to \mathbb C \qquad  \qquad (*)
  $$
be a sesqui-linear form such that
$$
  |\varphi (x_1,x_2)|^2\leq \langle x_1,x_1\rangle _1\langle x_2,x_2\rangle _2, \quad\forall (x_1,x_2)\in H_1\times H_2.
  $$
Should $H_1$ and $H_2$ be Hilbert spaces, this would be simply written as
$$
  |\varphi (x_1,x_2)|\leq \|x_1\|\|x_2\|.
  $$

For $x=(x_1, x_2)$ and $y=(y_1, y_2)$ in $H_1\times H_2$, put
$$
  \langle x,y\rangle _\varphi  =   \langle x_1,y_1\rangle _1 +\varphi (x_1, y_2)+ \overline {\varphi (y_1, x_2)}+  \langle x_2,y_2\rangle _2.
  $$

**Warm up exercise 1**.  Prove that, for every  $x=(x_1, x_2)\in H_1\times H_2$, one has that $\langle x,x\rangle _\varphi \geq 0$.

We may then give the following:

**Definition**.  The semi-direct product of $H_1$ and $H_2$ relative to $\varphi $, denoted
$H_1\bowtie_\varphi  H_2$,
is the Hilbert
space completion of $H_1\times H_2$ under the pre-inner product $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle _\varphi $, after the subspace formed by the vectors of norm zero
is modded out.

Observe that the map
$$
  \iota _1:x_1\in H_1\mapsto (x_1, 0)\in H_1\bowtie_\varphi  H_2
  $$
may be viewed as an isometry  in the
sense that
$$
  \|\iota _1(x_1)\| = \sqrt{\langle x_1,x_1\rangle_1 }, \quad\forall x_1\in H_1,
  $$
and similarly for $H_2$.

It is then easy to show that
$$
\langle\iota_1(x_1),\iota_2(x_2)\rangle=\varphi(x_1,x_2),
$$
for all $x_1\in H_1$ and $x_2\in H_2$.

**Warm up exercise 2**.  Given any Hilbert-space $H$,  and given subspaces $H_1, H_2\subseteq H$,   consider the sesqui-linear
form
$$
  \varphi :(x_1, x_2)\in H_1\times H_2\to \langle x_1, x_2\rangle \in \mathbb C,
  $$
and  prove that there is an isometric linear map from $H_1\bowtie_\varphi  H_2$ to $H$, sending each $(x_1, x_2)\in H_1\times H_2$ to $x_1+x_2$.

**Warm up super trivial exercise 3**.  Prove that  $H_1\bowtie_0 H_2\simeq H_1\oplus H_2$.

Ok, now to the real stuff:

**Question**.  Find natural  conditions on the sesqui-linear form  $\varphi $ given in   $(*)$, above, such that the orthogonal
projections from   $H_1\bowtie_\varphi  H_2$ to $H_1$ and to $H_2$ commute with each other.

---

PS 1: The motivation for this question is to outline a possible approach for answering
[Do GNS-projections of different tensor factors commute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466386/do-gns-projections-of-different-tensor-factors-commute), in the special
case of pure states.

The context there is of a pair of $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ (which I'm assuming unital for simplicity), and a state $\omega $ on
the (maximal) tensor product $A\otimes B$.   One can then define sesqui-linear forms on  $A$ and $B$ by
$$
  \langle x,y\rangle _A = \omega \big ((y^*x)\otimes 1\big ),\quad\forall x,y\in  A,
  $$
and
$$
  \langle x,y\rangle _B = \omega \big (1\otimes (y^*x)\big ),\quad\forall x,y\in  B,
  $$
and further define
$$
  \varphi :A\times B\to {\mathbb C},
  $$
by
$$
  \varphi (x,y)=\omega (x\otimes y^*).
  $$
In case $\omega $ is a pure state,
one would then attempt to check whether or not $\varphi $ obeys the conditions arising from the answer to the above
question.

---

PS 2: Another natural question would be to try to determine conditions on the sesqui-linear form  $\varphi $ given in   $(*)$,
above, such that $H_1+H_2$ is closed in   $H_1\bowtie_\varphi  H_2$.

---

Edit: PS 3: Should $H_1$ and $H_2$ be Hilbert spaces, then by Riesz there exists a bounded operator $T:H_1\to H_2$, such that
$$
\varphi(x_1,x_2) =\langle T(x_1),x_2\rangle_2.
$$
In this case, an answer to the above question is:  the projections mentioned there commute iff $T$ is a partial isometry, that is, $TT^*T=T$.

Although this is a nice result, I wouldn't consider it as being a condition on the sesqui-linear form $\varphi$ since it relies too much on geometric aspects of operators. In particular this would be hard to check in the application to (PS1).

Comment: It looks like if you replace $H_i$ with $\overline{H_i/N_i}$ the Hilbert completion of $H_i$ mod its nullspace and apply your construction you get the same space, with the same image of $H_i$. But here you have already given a complete characterisation.

Comment: @s.harp, in fact I am not very happy with this characterization because I can't see how to use it in the intended application to my (PS1) above.  Do you see a way forward?

Comment: No. I guess the extreme cases are if it comes from a projection or a unitary, which could be investigated. But are you sure about your characterisation? For example if $\varphi = \frac12 \langle,\rangle$ don't you also get $H_1\oplus H_2$, but it doesnt come from a partial isometry.

Comment: @s.harp. The case you mention, that is $H_1=H_2=H$, and $\varphi (x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle /2$, indeed corresponds to $H\bowtie_\varphi  H = H\oplus H$, except that
from the point of view of $H\oplus H$, the embeddings are
  $$
  \iota _1(x)=(x,0)
  $$
  and
  $$
  \iota _2(y)=(y/2,\sqrt 3 y/2),
  $$
  so the projections onto $\iota _1(H)$ and  $\iota _2(H)$ do not commute.